# Profiling iphone with shark: Nothing happens after pressing start

Tags: iphone, profiling, shark

I have used shark in the past with Mac applications. I am now trying to set it up for the iPhone but it doesn't want to work.

I have followed these instruction from another post:
Build app and launch on device

```
- Launch Shark
- From the Shark menu, select Sampling->Network/iPhone Profiling
- In the Shark window, select the radio button "Control network profiling of shared computers".
- Select your iPhone in the list and optionally configure the profiling session
- Press Start to begin profiling, and Stop to end
```

Everything is fine except the final step. I press start and nothing happens... it is really frustrating since the start button is not greyed out and shark just fail silently without any further message.

I have tried to:

```
- Reboot
- Re-install latest XCode
- Restore my ipod
- Try different USB port
- Disabling firewall
```

Anyone has another suggestion or have seen that in the past?

Answer (score 8):

Apparently Apple have dropped support for shark and iOS 4... we should use the app called Instruments instead.

I have read this on apple dev forums:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/243237 (if you can access it)

Comment: This really sux, shark is way better than instruments.

Comment: Make sure to manually add the "Time Profiler" instrument.  It is considered the replacement for Shark.